# Detecting if bit set in numeric value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, syntax

I have a tinyint column that represents a set of flags. Assuming I wanted to know if a specific bit was set or not, how can I do bitwise AND/OR in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your previous questions you use SQL Server. So you can use the [& operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx).

e.g. to see if the bit for 4 is on (and assuming `NULL` should return `NULL`)

```
SELECT CASE number & 4 WHEN 4 THEN 1 WHEN 0 THEN 0 END
```